# CSP (Content Security Policy) for Google Ad Manager Website

Tags: javascript, c#, html

How do we write a good (secure) CSP for a website using Google Ad Manager.

I don't want to use something like script-src * because it's considered insecure.

But I have literally hundreds of potential script sources (my ads.txt is about 350 lines long). Of these about four or five different sources will be included in a typical page - depending on the header bidding/auction process.